# How to align one normal line bullet and another used in a column into same position?

Tags: beamer, bullets

[image]

As shown above, one line starts in a normal line. Then I use a column. Then the second line is coming from the column. But I want to have these two lines to start from the same position. Please any one help here. The code used in beamer here.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Line starts in a normal
\end{itemize}
\begin{columns}[c]
 \column {0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item Line starts in a column
\end{itemize}
\end{columns} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compile. Which documentclass do you use?

Comment: I am using \documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

Comment: Does "same position" means same vertical or same horizontal position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

For above result you need to specify both columns and prescribed smaller width of columns, for example `o.45\linewidth` (found by trial):

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Line starts in a normal
\end{itemize}
\begin{columns}[c]
    \column {0.45\textwidth} % <---
\begin{itemize}
\item Line starts in a column
\end{itemize}
   \column {0.45\textwidth}  % <---
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank You so much. This works

Answer (score 1):

By default, beamer removes the usual margins in a `columns` environment and replaces them with a `\hfill`. You can simply use the `onlytextwidth` option to get the same margins as in normal text.

This can either be done locally, see the example below, or globally with `\documentclass[onlytextwidth]{beamer}`.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Line starts in a normal
\end{itemize}
\begin{columns}[c,onlytextwidth]
 \column {0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item Line starts in a column
\end{itemize}
\end{columns} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]